# Can default constructor that does nothing affect performance?

Tags: c++, performance, constructor

I was going through [**source code**](https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/) of [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/) and got stumbled upon the [following code](https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Common/b2Math.h#53).

```
/// A 2D column vector.
struct b2Vec2
{
        /// Default constructor does nothing (for performance).
        b2Vec2() {}

        ...
}
```

The constructor is not initializing any fields or doing any operation for that matter.

How can having or not having an empty constructor affect performance?

Comment: There's a second way to read that comment - `///// Default constructor does nothing , as opposed to doing something (for performance).`

Comment: The person who wrote that comment did not by any chance provide measurement results?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore : Doing or not doing something in the constructor is a matter of functionality. Why should performance matter in that aspect?

Comment: @ChristianHackl : There is nothing else in the source regarding the constructor apart from that comment. You can see it yourself here. https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Common/b2Math.h

Comment: I'm guessing `b2Vec2` has two data members. A typical default constructor implementation would zero initialize these, but this one doesn't because ... performance apparently.

Comment: @TanmayPatil: I was being a little bit sarcastic here. My point was that programmers just love to claim things about code performance without ever measuring execution speed, or without measuring it under realistic circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it didn't exist, then you could only create an object using the other constructor. That constructor initialises the data members, which is slower than not initialising them. So you can use this constructor for performance reasons if you don't need to give them values yet.